# Tweeting Videos Using Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, twitter, tweepy

I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to Tweet out small-length videos using Tweepy. I tried to do it using the `update_with_media` function, but got this error:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: File is too big, must be less than 3072kb.
```

If anyone knows if it's possible, let me know please!

Comment: The message is unambiguous: the video is NOT small-length. Make it shorter.

Comment: Twitter allows I think at least 30 seconds of video. The one I tested was 19 seconds. Not sure how much smaller I can get without it being not worth it.

Comment: Perhaps you should reduce the quality by increasing the compression ratio.

Comment: What is the file size of your 19 seconds video? Your error says it cannot be bigger 3 megabytes.

Comment: I got it down to 1 mg just to see if it'll work, but I don't think tweepy recognizes video files

Answer (score 0):

Support for uploading videos has been added to Tweepy with https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1486. It will be released as part of v4.0.